# Multiple gridview as mutiple worksheet of a single excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, datatable

I have two datatables. I want to make two gridviews for each of them. Then I want to render those gridviews in a single excel file but as two separate worksheets. I've searched for this, but didn't get anything as I want. Can any one show me the way?

Here is my sample code for single worksheet using one gridview:

```
DataTable dt = createDataTbl(); // creating a datatable
grid.DataSource = dt;
grid.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.xls");

Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#007ACC");
grid.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
byte[] fileContents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Response.ToString());
return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check. Actually I've created a excel file which contains single worksheet using single gridview. But I am finding a way to make multiple worksheet using multiple gridview.